# Recommended way to perform Lucene search without limit

Tags: full-text-search, lucene

The Lucene [documents](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query%29) tell me that "Hits" will be removed from the API in Lucene 3.0.

> **Deprecated**. Hits will be removed in
>   Lucene 3.0. Use search(Query, Filter,
>   int) instead.

The proposed overload limits the number of documents returned to the value of the int.

So my question is: what is the recommended way to perform a search in Lucene with no limit on the number of documents to be returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highest integer in Java is pretty darned high, you could use [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) for the limit. I bet something else breaks before you actually hit the limit of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) documents. :-)

Alternately, you can use a `HitCollector`: [`search(Query query, HitCollector results)`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.HitCollector)) or [`search(Query query, Filter filter, HitCollector results)`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20org.apache.lucene.search.HitCollector)); the docs say:

> Applications should only use this if they need all of the matching documents

Comment: Setting the topcount to a high enough value indeed is the easiest answer.  If I really would have needed everything then the custom HitCollector would have been the ideal solution.  But i'd rather just use the high-level search api.

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah, that makes the most sense to me as well. :-)